# Using r8 register as a loop counter results in endless loop - why?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

The following code prints hello world 10 times by using the rsi register as a loop counter.

```
section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10   
    helloLen:  equ $-hello             

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rsi, 0                 ;<--- use r8 here

do_loop:
    inc rsi                    ;<--- use r8 here

    ;print hello world
    mov eax,4             
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,hello       
    mov edx,helloLen     

    int 80h              

    cmp rsi, 10                ;<--- use r8 here
    jnz do_loop

    ;system exit
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

If I am trying to use the r8 register instead of rsi as a loop counter it results in an endless loop. The r8 register here is just an example. It happens for the registers r9, r10 as well.

Could someone explain this, because I thought these are all general purpose registers and you should be allowed to use them?

Comment: You are using the 32 bit system calls in 64 bit mode. Bad idea.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe Linux's `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI clobbers upper registers when called from 64-bit code?  In Linux, `syscall` clobbers rcx and r11, but preserves everything else (except rax for the return value, of course).  Usually people run into problems with the `int 0x80` ABI when trying to pass pointers that don't fit in 32 bits.  (Resulting in `-EFAULT`)

Comment: Try single-stepping in gdb with `layout reg` to highlight regs that change.  (See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: okay, changing the block which prints the string "hello world" to a 64 bit system call resolves the issue. There must be a weird side effect in this block.

Comment: Not only the upper bits, but the 64 bit extra registers as a whole are not saved by the 32 bit syscall for obvious reasons. Hardly "weird".

Comment: @Jester: If you don't know how the kernel side of things works, guessing that an interrupt handler saves/restores the full x86-64 state when coming from long-mode user-space is not a bad guess.  But I assume the handler for interrupt vector `0x80` is different from the handlers for other interrupts, and uses its own save/restore code.  (Also, what's a good term for r8-r15?  I said "upper registers", but I guess that sounds like the upper halves of rax-rsp.  AMD considered calling them UAX/UCX etc. instead of r8/r9 etc.  "extra 64bit registers" seems clumsy :/).

Comment: Well, the situation seems to be different than I thought, the [compatibility int 80 handler](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.6/arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S#L313-L329) actually explicitly zeroes registers `r8` through `r11` and preserves the full 64 bits of the others (except for `rax` which is of course the return value).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** : `int 0x80` implicitly **zeroes** out ***R8***, *R9*, *R10*, and *R11* on 64-bit Linux systems prior to returning to userland code. This behavior occurs on kernels later than 2.6.32-rc1. This is not the case for the preferred 64-bit *SYSCALL* calling convention.

---

You are experiencing a peculiarity of the Linux Kernels after version 2.6.32-rc1. For Linux kernel versions <= 2.6.32-rc1 you may get the behaviour you were expecting. Due to an information leakage bug (and exploits) the registers *R8*, *R9*, *R10*, and *R11* are now zeroed out when the kernel returns from an `int 0x80`.

You may believe that these registers shouldn't matter in compatibility mode (32-bit code) since those newer registers are unavailable. This is a false assumption as it's possible for a 32-bit application to switch into 64-bit long mode and access those registers. The [Linux Kernel Mailing List post](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/10/1/164) that identified this issue had this to say:

> x86: Don't leak 64-bit kernel register values to 32-bit processes
>
> While 32-bit processes can't directly access R8...R15, they can gain
>   access to these registers by temporarily switching themselves into
>   64-bit mode.

Code that demonstrates register leakage on the earlier kernels was made available by [Jon Oberheide](https://jon.oberheide.org/files/cve-2009-2910.c). It creates a 32-bit application to be run on an x86-64 system with IA32 compatibility enabled. The program switches to 64-bit long mode and then stores registers *R8*-*R11* into general purpose registers that are available in compatibility mode (32-bit mode). John discusses the specifics in this [article](https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2009/10/04/linux-kernel-x86-64-register-leak/). He sums the vulnerability and the kernel fix nicely in this excerpt:

> **The Vulnerability**
>
> The underlying issue that causes this vulnerability is a lack of
>   zeroing out several of the x86-64 registers upon returning from a
>   syscall.  A 32-bit application may be able to switch to 64-bit mode
>   and access the **r8, r9, r10, and r11** registers to leak their previous
>   values.  This issue was discovered by Jan Beulich and patched on
>   October 1st.  **The fix is obviously to zero out these registers to
>   avoid leaking any information to userspace**.

---

If you were to step through your code in a debugger like *GDB* you should discover that *R8* is in fact set to zero after `int 0x80`. Since it is your loop counter your program ends up in an endless cycle printing `Hello world!`.